# Solving recurrence relation for asymptotic analysis

Tags: asymptotics

How to solve the recursion:

$
T(n) = 
\begin{cases}
T(n/2) + O(1),  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
2T(\lceil n/2 \rceil) + O(1), & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$

I know that it can be written as O(n). But I want to find a tighter bound. For example, when dealing with powers of two, T(n) is O(logn), which will most probably allow for a tighter bound overall.

So, how to solve this recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $n = 2^m + 1$. Then
$$
T(n) \geq 2T(2^{m-1}+1) \geq 4T(2^{m-2}+1) \geq \cdots,
$$
and so $T(n) = \Omega(n)$ for $n$ of this form. Therefore you cannot get a better worst-case bound than $O(n)$.

In more detail, this example shows that if $T(n) = O(f(n))$ for a monotone function $f(n)$ then $f(n) = \Omega(n)$. You might be able to get an upper bound using more information on $n$.

---

Let's analyze a similar but slightly simpler recursion,
$$
S(n) = \begin{cases} S(n/2) + 1 & \text{if $n>0$ is even}, \\ 2S(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + 1 & \text{if $n$ is odd},\\ 0 & \text{if $n = 0$}. \end{cases}
$$
Let us denote
$$
S(a_1,\ldots,a_k) = S(2^{a_1} + \cdots + 2^{a_k}),
$$
where we implicitly assume that $a_1 > \cdots > a_k$. We have
$$
\begin{align*}
S(a_1,\ldots,a_k) &= 1 + S(a_1-1,\ldots,a_k-1) \\ &=
2 + S(a_1-2,\ldots,a_k-2) \\ &= \cdots \\ &=
a_k + S(a_1-a_k,a_2-a_k,\ldots,a_{k-1}-a_k,0) \\ &=
a_k + 1 + 2S(a_1-a_k-1,a_2-a_k-1,\ldots,a_{k-1}-a_k-1) \\ &=
(a_k + 1) + 2(a_{k-1}-a_k) + 4S(a_1-a_{k-1}-1,\ldots,a_{k-2}-a_{k-1}-1) \\ &=
(a_k+1) + 2(a_{k-1}-a_k) + 4(a_{k-2}-a_{k-1}) + \cdots + 2^{k-1}(a_1-a_2) \\ &=
2^{k-1} a_1 - 2^{k-2} a_2 - \cdots - a_k + 1.
\end{align*}
$$
Notice now that
$$
2^{k-1} a_1 - 2^{k-2} a_2 - \cdots - a_k + 1 \geq \\
2^{k-1} a_1 - 2^{k-2} (a_1 - 1) - \cdots - (a_k - (k-1)) + 1 = \\
a_1 + 2^k - k,
$$
and on the other hand,
$$
2^{k-1} a_1 - 2^{k-2} a_2 - \cdots - a_k + 1 \leq \\
2^{k-1} a_1 - 2^{k-2} (k-2) - 2^{k-3} (k-3) - \cdots - 0 + 1 = \\
2^{k-1} (a_1 - k + 3) - 1.
$$
This gives us a lower bound of $\Omega(\log n + 2^{|n|})$ and an upper bound of $O(n)$, where $|n|$ is the Hamming weight; note that if $n = 2^m-1$ then the lower bound is linear in $n$. Indeed,
$$
S(2^m-1) = 1 + 2S(2^{m-1}-1) = 1 + 2 + 4S(2^{m-2}-1) = \cdots = \\ 1 + 2 + 4 + \cdots + 2^{m-1} S(1) = 2^m-1.
$$

---

It is likely that you can find a similar formula for $T$.

Comment: Is a tighter upper bound possible?

Comment: Have you read my answer at all?

Comment: I jumped straight to the end of the answer!

Comment: If $T(n) = O(f(n))$ then $f(n) = \Omega(n)$. You might be able to get a better bound in terms of other parameters, such as (in the case of $S(n)$) the Hamming weight of $n$.

Comment: would we able to get  tighter worse case upper bound if $T(n) = 2T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)+1$ for odd $n$

Comment: No, you will still have bad examples, they would just be different (take $n = 2^m - 1$).

Comment: sorry for extending this in the comments. What about the case when $T(n) = T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + T(\lceil n/2 \rceil) + 1$

Comment: You'll have to seek the truth on this one on your own. I suggest programming it and doing some experiments.